How can I get a simpler way to draw a solid?
Let two circles center $O_1$, radius $10$ and  center $O_2$, radius $6$ so that $AB$ is a diameter of the circle center $O_2$.  I am trying to draw solid when rotate the filled region around line $O_1O_2$.

Based on this answer I tried
Clear["Global`*"];
r1 = 10;
r2 = 6;
cir1[t_] := {r1  Cos[t], r1  Sin[t]};
cir2 [s_] := {8 + r2  Cos[s], r2  Sin[s]};
ParametricPlot[{{r1  Cos[t], r1  Sin[t]}, {8 + r2  Cos[s], 
   r2  Sin[s]}}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False]
reg = ParametricPlot[{{r1  Cos[t], r1  Sin[t]}, {8 + r2  Cos[s], 
    r2  Sin[s]}}, {t, -ArcCos[4/5], ArcCos[4/5]}, {s, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  Mesh -> False]
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[
  cir1[t] // Evaluate, {t, -ArcCos[4/5], ArcCos[4/5]}, 
  RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}], 
 RevolutionPlot3D[cir2[s] // Evaluate, {s, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False]

To find the points $A, B$, I solve the system of equations
Solve[{(x - 8)^2 + y^2 == 36, x^2 + y^2 == 100}, {x, y}, Reals]


{{x -> 8, y -> -6}, {x -> 8, y -> 6}}




I have to find the angle $\arccos(4/5)$ by hand.

{s0, t0} = {s, t} /.    First@Solve[{cir2[s] == cir1[t], 0 <= s <= π,       0 <= t <= π}, {s, t}]

CSGRegion["Difference", {Ball[{8, 0, 0}, 6], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10]}]


We can use {s0, t0} = {s, t} /.  First@FindInstance[{cir2[s] == cir1[t], 0 <= s <= π,  0 <= t <= π}, {s, t}]  to find the two range.
Clear["Global`*"];
r1 = 10;
r2 = 6;
cir1[t_] := {r1   Cos[t], r1   Sin[t]};
cir2[s_] := {8 + r2   Cos[s], r2   Sin[s]};
{s0, t0} = {s, t} /. 
  First@FindInstance[{cir2[s] == cir1[t], 0 <= s <= π, 
     0 <= t <= π}, {s, t}] 
(* Show[ParametricPlot[cir1[t],{t,0,t0}],ParametricPlot[cir2[s],{s,0,\
s0}],PlotRange->All] *)
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[cir1[t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, t0}, 
  RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t, θ}, Hue@θ], 
  PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2], 
 RevolutionPlot3D[cir2[s] // Evaluate, {s, 0, s0}, 
  RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t, θ}, Hue@θ], 
  PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 2], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
  PlotRange -> All]


